# Find Object in JSON Array

Tags: php, json, linkedin-api

I cannot for the life of me find the correct syntax to return an element in a JSON array

The array is

```
{
"_total": 1,
"values": [{
"isCommentable": true,
"isLikable": true,
"isLiked": false,
"numLikes": 0,
"timestamp": 1453718959851,
"updateComments": {"_total": 0},
"updateContent": {
  "company": {
    "id": 2691316,
    "name": "Rising 5th Web Design"
  },
  "companyStatusUpdate": {"share": {
    "comment": "This is a test update for testing the jQuery REST API",
    "id": "s6097339248095035392",
    "source": {
      "serviceProvider": {"name": "LINKEDIN"},
      "serviceProviderShareId": "s6097339248095035392"
    },
    "timestamp": 1453718959851,
    "visibility": {"code": "anyone"}
  }}
},
"updateKey": "UPDATE-c2691316-6097339248082460672",
"updateType": "CMPY"
}]
}
```

The element I'm trying to get to is

"comment": "This is a test update for testing the jQuery REST API"

But for no good reason I cannot figure out the syntax of how I walk the PHP to this element.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its a static json than you can get as by using `json_decode`:

```
$content = json_decode($string, true); 
echo $content['values'][0]['updateContent']['companyStatusUpdate']['share']['comment'];
```

**Explanation:**

First of all decode your `json` and get the right index.

Note that, in this example i am using second parameter of `json_decode()` function as `true` if you ignore this param than you will get the decoded result in `OBJECT` form.

Answer (score 1):

Try get your json in a variable and use [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to decode your json in php.

```
//json variable.
$json ='{
"_total": 1,
"values": [{
"isCommentable": true,
"isLikable": true,
"isLiked": false,
"numLikes": 0,
"timestamp": 1453718959851,
"updateComments": {"_total": 0},
"updateContent": {
  "company": {
    "id": 2691316,
    "name": "Rising 5th Web Design"
  },
  "companyStatusUpdate": {"share": {
    "comment": "This is a test update for testing the jQuery REST API",
    "id": "s6097339248095035392",
    "source": {
      "serviceProvider": {"name": "LINKEDIN"},
      "serviceProviderShareId": "s6097339248095035392"
    },
    "timestamp": 1453718959851,
    "visibility": {"code": "anyone"}
  }}
},
"updateKey": "UPDATE-c2691316-6097339248082460672",
"updateType": "CMPY"
}]
}';

// decode json
    $c = json_decode($json, true);
// get your element
    echo $c['values'][0]['updateContent']['companyStatusUpdate']['share']['comment'];
```